# Altering only the Hours/Minutes part of a DateTime object in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I got a ViewModel with StartTime(Datetime) and EndTime(DateTime) properties. On my edit form, there are TimePickers (KENDO UI) that display the hh:mm, and the end user can alter the hours.

Now, I have a object with dates in december 2017. When selecting a new value in the TimePicker, it also sets the yyyy/mm/dd to 2018/01/03.

Is there a solution to prevent the timepicker from changing anything else than HH:mm? If not, and if I add a 'oldtime' property to store the old values, can I put the original yyyy/mm/dd values in the new DateTime object or just replace the hh/mm?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a solution to prevent the timepicker from changing anything else than HH:mm?

The TimePicker isn't at fault, C# / .NET doesn't have separate Time and Date types. So they operate on a DateTime that always has y/m/d components.

> can I put the original yyyy/mm/dd values in the new DateTime object

Sure.

```
var newDateTime = oldDateTime.Date + timePicker.DateTimeValue.TimeOfDay;
```

`DateTime.Date` gives you midnight at the beginning of the day (at 00:00:00) and `DateTime.TimeOfDay` gives you the opposite, a `TimeSpan` offset from midnight. Together they let you mix and match Date and Time with ease.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it!